# Single Product - Multiple Add To Cart

Tags: addtocart, magento-1.9

I would like to have single items displayed in category without prices, once customer has clicked on product and the product view page is loaded, I would like multiple add to cart options. Something clean that would provide something like this...is there an extension maybe that could apply to each product I have?

Thanks for any help...

Red ADD TO CART (button)
Blue ADD TO CART (button)
GREEN ADD TO CART (button)

OR 

20 COUNT ADD TO CART (button)
100 COUNT ADD TO CART (button)
1000 ADD TO CART (button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the color part I suggest to use the `Custom Options` in your Product configuration.

If your template don't allow to input the Qty for a product you can create own buttons in your template file where you can use `$this->getSubmitUrl($_product)` and add `/qty/20` or `/qty/100` etc behind the url.

Something like this also:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product); ?>/qty/20" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_20">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, custom options should work well for me. One problem. My hope, example product, Drumsticks. In category: supplies, photo of drumsticks will appear. Plan to disable price & add to cart button for products in category view. Want customer to click on drumstick image to find product choices. Your described configurable product options. Want the customer to choose 20 sticks, 100 sticks, 1000 sticks. Problem is, original product has a price already associated with it. If customer select 20 stick they will add the original sticks and the 20 to cart. Want only 20 stick add to cart? Thoughts?

Comment: Well, I would try to solve this issue with [Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)

Comment: I believe I may have just figured it out :-) I set the original drumstick price as zero, then the customer is forced to choose one or more of the options, the price accumulates if multiple selections are made and customer hits add to cart once. This should work for my needs. Clean as well even for the responsive mobile customer. Thanks for all your help! I assumed price must be higher than $.00.

Comment: You're welcome, just make sure you options are required, so the customer is forced to choose one.

Comment: May I ask, in your previous reply, you show code for creation of the ADD TO CART Qty Buttons...In what file should this be added please. I would like to explore this option as well.

Comment: Well creating a form for each button isn't the best example, but if you want explore and play around  have a look in `catalog/product/view.phtml`